# PHP: Unexpected results from 'rtrim' function

Tags: php, trim, php-5.5

I'm collecting a series of URL's, I'm using the rtrim function to remove 'index.html' from the end of the URL's. Occasionally rtrim removes more than expected however, for example:

I have the url: ***www.bikes.com/bike-accessories/hydration/index.html***

Using this function, where $path short contains the a string of the URL:

```
$path_short = rtrim($path_short, '/index.html');
```

I am left with: ***www.bikes.com/bike-accessories/hydratio***

Doesn anyone know why this might be?

Comment: rtrim works with a __list of character__, it's not simply removing a fixed string from the end, but every instance of the individual characters `/` or `i` or `n` or `d` or `e` or `x` or `.` etc..... [RTFM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's simply a case of poster not having read the documentation

Comment: Ah I see, what is the best solution to achieve the results I'm hoping for here?

Comment: If you want to remove a fixed length, then use [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) instead.... `$path_short = substr($path_short, 0, -11);` if necessary applying an `if` test to be sure that is the content at the end of $path_short

Comment: Although for URLs and filepaths, [pathinfo()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) may be a better alternative

Answer (score 2):

This happened because rtrim Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string. It takes all the characters separately and not as a word. You have mentioned `n` in `index.html`, therefore `hydration` lost one `n` from the right leaving only `hydratio`.

Use [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function instead like below.

`$pathInfo = pathinfo('www.bikes.com/bike-accessories/hydration/index.html');`

`$pathInfo['dirname']` will give `www.bikes.com/bike-accessories/hydration`